# Como posso verificar se um objeto existe no dicionário e retorná-lo

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, estrutura-de-dados, dicionário

Estou a trabalhar numa solução em que devo entrar sobre a mesma função com um determinado nome de um Parque. Os parques estão implementados numa lista e cada parque tem um nome. Acontece que pretendo e já tentei desenvolver uma função em que ao pesquisar um parque o mesmo deve ser devolvido (escrito) ou deve aparecer uma mensagem semelhante a "Nâo foi encontrado".

Eu estou a trabalhar por camadas em C# (que é onde estou a desenvolver a app) e na DL (Data Layer) tenho um dicionario de `Park`, classe que tem sobre a mesma uma Lista de `Automoveis`, e uma Lista de `ParkedAuto`que corresponde a um conjunto de automóveis estacionados num parque.

Eis o método que tenho na DL:

```
 public static bool DevolveParque(string fileName, string nomeParque)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open);
                    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                    parques = (Dictionary<string, Park>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                    return true;


                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Console.Write("ERRO:" + e.Message);

                }


                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Park> x in parques)
                {

                    if (parques.ContainsKey(nomeParque))
                    {
                         Console.WriteLine("Nome: " + x.Key);
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
```

Se repararam bem eu aqui, testo com uma instrução decisiva, (um `if`), se o meu parques tem uma chave que corresponde na verdade ao nome do parque, existente no Dicionario Parques (`static Dictionary<string, Park> parques = new Dictionary<string, Park>();`)

Ao fazer debugging o programa que está em execução encontra a chave (que por definição corresponde ao nome do parque) mas não demonstra o parque, nem tão pouco me diz que não foi encontrado.

Como posso alterar isso.

Nota: Estou a trabalhar com ficheiros (arquivos), os mesmos tem Parques e também tem vários veículos dentro dos parques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque o trecho:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Park> x in parques)
{
    if (parques.ContainsKey(nomeParque))
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Nome: " + x.Key);
    }
}
```

Para

```
if(parques.ContainsKey(nomeParque)) {
    Park park = parques[nomeParque];
    Console.WriteLine(/* Imprimir aqui o que quer do objeto park*/);
}   
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Não encontrado!");
}
```

Não há porquê iterar pelos itens do dicionário, já que a chave é única, basta verificar se ela existe e obter seu valor, no caso o objeto `Park`. Mas isso julgando que o seu dicionário tenha sido carregado corretamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda MarcusVinicius ;)

Comment: Ai esta minha mania de usar ciclos for e foreach ... tenho que ter mais calma e cuidado